# Add subview not working?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, subview

I have two xib files:

MainView.xib and DetailView.xib

Both are controlled by MainViewController. MainView.xib loads when the app first opens, but if a user clicks on a button, the app loads DetailView.xib as a subview.

DetailView should load because I made an IBOutlet in the MainViewController to the view in the DetailView.xib file.

I am trying to use the addSubview command, but for some reason it is not actually executing the command. It will go through the command, but nothing will actually change. Here is the command:

```
[self.view addSubview:myDetailView]
```

where myDetailView is the IBOutlet

What is wrong with this setup?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

MainViewController.h (left generated code out):

```
IBOutlet UIView *myDetailView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myDetailView;
```

MainViewController.m:

```
@synthesize myDetailView;
```

Comment: How are you loading `DetailView.xib`?

Comment: Can you post more code showing how you instantiate your myDetailView?

Comment: You may try `insertSubview:` instead so that you can control the z index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLog myDetailView before you add the subview, and if it returns "(null)" then the myDetailView has not been initialised. Make sure that you have connected the view in Interface Builder.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", myDetailView); is giving no output at all. I even put NSLog(@"Test"); next to it and that printed, but the detailView one didn't.

Comment: IT IS NULL! Why would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I bet myDetailView is nil.
It may be an IBOutlet, but it has to be connected. And the XIB in which you connected the IBOutlet should obviously be loaded.

How did you load the DetailView.xib in your code? Did you use `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`?